# Is there a way for me to see the attributes of a Application element in production?

Tags: blueprism

I'm in the middle of a RPA project at my work. 
In the routine, a enterprise application is accessed many times and in some of those times it throws an error saying that "No element matched the query terms".

I guess there's some attribute in the window I'm trying to match that changes frequently, however every time I stop the process to check the issue, it doesn't happen...

I want to know if there's some way to grab the attributes identified of the window and store them in a log so I can compare between the attributes mapped and the ones intermittently observed in production.

Comment: What version of Blue Prism are you using?

Comment: The BP version is 6.4, @esqew

Comment: Sometimes apps lag a bit and blueprism might query element before it appeared. Try waiting for an element to appear?